# Does quantum computers give any advantage over classical computers in Sudoku?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-advantage

To my basic knowledge I know that solving a generalized Sudoku problems is an NP-complete problem so, is there any possible way quantum computers give an advantage over classical computers in this type of problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184908/1271772) that solving Sudoku for $n^2 \times n^2$ grids with $n\times n$ blocks is an NP complete problem.

The quantum complexity class BQP is the class of decision problems solvable by a quantum computer in polynomial time (with an error probability of at most 1/3 in all cases). The relationship between BQP and the classical complexity classes P and NP-Complete is currently an open problem, but most experts think that quantum computers cannot solve NP-Complete problems in polynomial time:

[image]

This is an excerpt from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) Wikipedia article:

> It is suspected that NP $ \nsubseteq $ BQP; that is, it is believed
>   that there are efficiently checkable problems that are not efficiently
>   solvable by a quantum computer. As a direct consequence of this
>   belief, it is also suspected that BQP is disjoint from the class of
>   NP-complete problems (if an NP-complete problem were in BQP, then it
>   would follow from NP-hardness that all problems in NP are in BQP).

Therefore quantum comptuers are unlikely to be able to solve an $n^2 \times n^2$ Sudoku puzzle in polynomial time. It is quite possible that quantum computers will have to pay $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ to solve the puzzle, as would be the case for classical computers, however this doesn't rule out the possibility that the quantum computer could beat the classical computer by having a smaller constant hidden under the big O, or by having a smaller pre-factor in the exponent.

The original question:

> "is there any possible way quantum computers give an advantage over
>   classical computers in this type of problem?"

is a bit vague, because what is meant by "advantage" ?
Many people would only consider it to be an "advantage" if there is there is an improvement in the scaling of the cost with respect to $n$, which is why at first I mentioned computational complexity considerations. However if you just want to know whether or not a quantum computer can finish the puzzle with fewer logic gates than a classical computer, of course the quantum computer will have an advantage because all classical computers ***are*** quantum computers, so by definition there is absolutely no way a classical computer can finish the puzzle with fewer gates. Whether or not quantum gates can be performed as efficiently (energy-wise) compared to classical gates though, is [an open problem](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2019/2293). So the answer depends on what you consider to be an "advantage" and how you define things, but you can certainly define things in a way in which a quantum computer would have an advantage.